# Object arrays not supported on numpy with mkl?

Tags: numpy, sympy, intel-mkl, openblas

I recently switched from numpy compiled with open blas to numpy compiled with mkl. In pure numeric operations there was a clear speed up for matrix multiplication. However when I ran some code I have been using which multiplies matrices containing sympy variables, I now get the error

'Object arrays are not currently supported'

Does anyone have information on why this is the case for mkl and not for open blas?

Comment: Matrix multiplications using MKL only works on Float arrays in single (np.float32,np.complex64) or double precision (np.float64,np.complex128). All other are not supported by MKL, but there are C/Cython implementations in Numpy which work with some other dtypes too. (but quite a lot slower) https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm

Answer (score 1):

Release notes for 1.17.0

```
Support of object arrays in matmul
It is now possible to use matmul (or the @ operator) with object arrays. For instance, it is now possible to do:

from fractions import Fraction
a = np.array([[Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 3)], [Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 2)]])
b = a @ a
```

Are you using `@` (`matmul` or `dot`)? A `numpy` array containing `sympy` objects will be object `dtype`. Math on object arrays depends on delegating the action to the object's own methods. It cannot be performed by the fast compiled libraries, which only work with `c` types such as `float` and `double`.

As a general rule you should not be trying to mix `numpy` and `sympy`. Math is hit-or-miss, and never fast. Use `sympy's` own `Matrix` module, or `lambdify` the `sympy` expressions for numeric work.

What's the `mkl` version?  You may have to explore this with creator of that compilation.

Comment: I was using @. I think I compared timings using the sympy matrix module vs numpy @ and found @ faster for this particular use when I originally wrote the code.
https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/#files was what I was using. I guess the numpy version is just too old.